# Recover Exchange 2007 CCR Cluster

Tags: exchange-2007

I've just been tasket with recovering a failed Exchange 2007 CCR install for a customer.

It seems here that the operator has deleted the Cluster name and then added it again (effectively deleting the original cluster config from AD. So, my question is: Does anybody know how I can update ad with a "working" config to get this running again?

Comment: You may want to detail what, if any, Exchange/AD backup you have access to.